# Connecting a db2 database from a centos hosted laravel application

Tags: laravel, eloquent, centos, db2, db2-400

I'm trying to connect to a db2 database server (iseries ibm) from my laravel application (5.8). The application is running on a centos linux server.

I saw that db2 isn't in the 4 databases types listed here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#introduction.

So I tried to use that package https://github.com/cooperl22/laravel-db2 but I got the followings errors :

```
Undefined class constant 'I5_ATTR_DBC_SYS_NAMING'
```

And I've got the errors for 5 constants :
PDO::I5_ATTR_DBC_SYS_NAMING, PDO::I5_ATTR_COMMIT, PDO::I5_ATTR_JOB_SORT, PDO::I5_ATTR_DBC_LIBL, PDO::I5_ATTR_DBC_CURLIB.

Also, if I comment theses constants, I got this error :

```
`Syntax error: -104 [IBM][CLI Driver][AS] SQL0104N An unexpected token "<END-OF-STATEMENT>" was found following "". Expected tokens may include: "( + - ? : DAY INF NAN RID ROW RRN". SQLSTATE=42601 (SQLNumResultCols[-104] at /root/PDO_IBM-1.3.6/ibm_driver.c:153) (SQL: select * from )`
```

I'm using the `db2_ibmi_ibm` driver.

Here is my php info linked to the driver :

[image: phpinfo]

**EDITED :**

php version is 7.3.4
centos version is 7

Also I made a from scratch php script running and I can get the results from a query using the db2_connection method. So I'm pretty sure it's PDO related :-/

Comment: Db2 on CentOS would be Db2 LUW, but you are using a driver to access Db2 for i...?

Comment: yes, the db2 isn't on centos, it's on a i server

Comment: Can you ping that Db2 server, is the port open?

Comment: @banibanc, also edit the question to include the laravel version, and whether you can connect to the database with same credentials from the bash command line on centos (using the Db2 client , I assume you either have a relevant licence or are going via Db2-connect gateway). the code 111 means CONNECTION REFUSED .

Comment: @banibanc , as your original symptom (-30081 code 111 ) is now solved, and you have an entirely different symptom, consider rewriting your question to show your code (removing the original symptom).

Comment: it's edited now :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the issue, my scheme and database were wrong, so the query wasn't correct.

The PDO constants are not needed in my case.

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Not sure how we could have helped with this as you never gave us enough information to troubleshoot.